# How to extract an entire data frame row if column value fulfills a statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe with 2 columns:

```
+-----------+----------+
|   Tweet   | Language |
+-----------+----------+
| some text | en       |
| more text | en       |
| ein text  | de       |
+-----------+----------+
```

(the text in the Tweet column are actual tweets)

I want to apply a language detection algorithm to see how many german(de) tweets I have in my df.

```
from langdetect import detect 
nlp = detect
```

This works, but only adds the tweet to temp_list

```
temp_list = [row for row in df['Tweet'] if nlp(row)=='de']
```

However, what I want, is to add the entire row to temp_list if the language detection algorithm labels it as german. I want to include both columns, so I can cross-check with my Language column(which I labeled manually).

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apply`

```
df[df['Language']==df['Tweet'].apply(nlp)]
```

and that would return a dataframe

You could also create a new column like `detected_lang`

```
df['detected_lang']=df['Tweet'].apply(nlp)
print(df)

       Tweet Language detected_lang
0  some text       en            sv
1  more text       en            en
2   ein text       de            de
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full dataframe output, and your dataframe is called `nlp` then you should use:

```
filtered_df = nlp[nlp['Language'] == 'de']
```

If you want only the `Tweets` column, then:

```
filtered_df = nlp[nlp['Language'] == 'de']['Tweets']
```

Finally, if you want to make a list out of those values:

```
df_filtered = df[df['Language'] =='de']['Tweets'].tolist()
```

### Outputs:

1st:

```
    Tweets Language
2  Deutsch       de
```

2nd:

```
2    Deutsch
```

3rd:

```
['Deutsch']
```